# How to get results of an stored procedure using SimpleJDBCCall in spring with two result table?

Tags: java, spring, stored-procedures, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm implementing a Spring+ MSSQL Server 2008 application. I use SimpleJDBCCall API to execute stored procedures and retrieve results.

For stored procedures with mono table results, it works fine, but I don't know how to use it for procedures with multi table results.
here is the screenshot from query of my database that returns two result table.[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/12JnI.jpg)

here is the code that i use,this code work properly with single table result`

```
public class LoadOnDemandSP extends StoredProcedure{
    private static final String SPROC_NAME = "sps_IME_EF_GetAllMarketData";

    public LoadOnDemandSP(DataSource ds) {
        super(ds, SPROC_NAME);

        RowMapper mapper = new MyRowMapper();
        declareParameter(new SqlReturnResultSet("Return Value", mapper));
        declareParameter(new SqlParameter("FromDate", Types.VARCHAR));
        declareParameter(new SqlParameter("ToDate",Types.VARCHAR));
        compile();

    }

    public List execute(String FromDate,String ToDate) {
        Map inputs = new HashMap();
        inputs.put("FromDate",FromDate);
        inputs.put("ToDate",ToDate);
        Map map = super.execute(inputs);
        if (map != null && map.size() > 0) {
            return (List) map.get("Return Value");
        } else {
            return new ArrayList();
        }


    }


    private class MyRowMapper implements RowMapper<LoadOnDemand> {
        public LoadOnDemand mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
            LoadOnDemand l = new LoadOnDemand();
//              f.setDay(rs.getInt("ContractDay"));
            l.setInternalQuantity(rs.getInt("DVaznTon"));
            l.setExportalQuantitiy(rs.getInt("SVaznTon"));
            l.setInternalValue(rs.getDouble("DArzeshMillion"));
            l.setExternalValue(rs.getDouble("SArzeshMillion"));
            l.setInternalBuyersCount(rs.getInt("DBuyers"));
            l.setExternalBuyersCount(rs.getInt("SBuyers"));
            l.setInternalSellersCount(rs.getInt("DSellers"));
            l.setExternalSellersCount(rs.getInt("SSellers"));
            l.setInternalGoodsCount(rs.getInt("DSymbols"));
            l.setExternalGoodsCount(rs.getInt("SSymbols"));
            l.setTablo(rs.getString("GrouhAsli"));
            return l;
        }
    }



}
```

///Added////

My sample SP:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sps_Test1]

WITH RECOMPILE      
AS

SELECT *

FROM dbo.tbl1

SELECT *

FROM dbo.tbl2
```

Comment: Could you show your storeprocedure?

Comment: i have just added sample procedure here

Answer (score 0):

You could not handle the multiple tables.  you can join the two  tables as one by using either `union` or `unionAll`

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sps_Test1]

WITH RECOMPILE      
AS

SELECT *

FROM dbo.tbl1
UNION
SELECT *

FROM dbo.tbl2
```

Comment: i have a difficult situation here,i am not admin of the database and i can not change store procedures at all,i can only change my java codes,do you have a suggestion for me?

Comment: then try with this http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.7/reference/jdbc.html#jdbc-StoredProcedure

Comment: you can try with this also http://www.xyzws.com/Javafaq/how-to-retrieve-multiple-result-sets-from-a-stored-procedure-in-jdbc/172